# CodeIgniter call same function for all controllers

Tags: codeigniter, function, controller, codeigniter-2

I'm developing an application, where the same function I'm writing for some controllers. So I wanted one common function for all controllers. Please help me out I've stucked up with this. The work would be more appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to share one common function among all controllers? I'm having trouble figuring out what you're asking

Comment: If you are indeed attempting to share a function between controllers, it should be part of a helper (or maybe library or model, depending on what that function does). In fact, depending on what the function does, you might even want to put it in a base controller class. We need more details.

Comment: I think a helper function would be nice.

Comment: If you go for a helper function you can't access your models though. For this I would suggest you to go for the `My Contoller` trick.

Comment: You can extend base class with other classes

Answer (score 3):

You can develop a helper or library.

codeigniter version 2 : https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/creating_libraries.html

codeigniter version 3 : https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html?highlight=library

Answer (score 2):

You can create `MY_Controller` class in `application/core`

```
Class MY_Controller Extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function common(){
        // code here
    }
}
```

Now extend every class with `MY_Controller` and the function 
will be available for each class

```
Class Test Extends MY_Controller{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

When in the url you call

```
http://localhost/app/test/common
```

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

create a model class and create that all function after that extend that model all  model classes .you can use one function different controller.other wise you can use Cms helper.this is the best way call a common function in different controller.