# How to call this function for every controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, autoloader

My situation is that, I have 20 controllers in my website, where I have a function like this.

```
$this->lang->load("main", $this->session->userdata("lang_code"));
```

How can I load this function in all the 20 controllers without adding it individually to the `__constructor` of every controller?

Comment: just found this seem like my case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20392648/codeigniter-call-same-function-for-all-controllers

Comment: Without hard work you will get nothing my friend.

Comment: as tip put your code in Model and call it in every controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a library for this purpose and autoload this library. Creating a library is explained in the given link
[codeigniter library](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html)

Or you can refer to a somewhat same question asked in the stackoverflow 
[Stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808769/how-to-get-a-functiona-automaticaly-load-in-every-function-of-controllers-in-cod)

Comment: Might be a good solution to create something like a library and then controlling by autoload.php in config folder.

Comment: Codeigniter 2 + User Guide Library New Location http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/creating_libraries.html

Answer (score 2):

try this

create the my_controller.php in application/core

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class My_controller extends CI_Controller {

       function My_controller()
       {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->lang->load("main", $this->session->userdata("lang_code"));

       }
    }
 ?>
```

in your controller

```
 class Your_controller extends MY_Controller {

 }
```

Comment: Thanks but seem like it not a good solution i'm looking for. by the way thank you very much for the answer.